# Writing Python 2.7 code that is as close to Python 3.x syntax as possible

Tags: python, python-3.x

Since Django doesn't yet support Python 3.x, I'm using Python 2.7. However, I'd like to go ahead and start familiarizing myself with the new Python 3.x syntax as much as possible. Which leads me to the question:

- What is the best way to write Python 2.7 code that will be as compatible as possible with Python 3.x?

I know that running `python -3` will

> Warn about Python 3.x incompatibilities that 2to3 cannot trivially fix.

However, I'm interested in getting used to Python 3.x syntax while still using Python 2.7.

For instance, it seems that I should be using the following imports to my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

The above four `__future__ import` statements are required as of Python 3.0, but not required in 2.7 as described in [Python 2.7.3's documentation 27.11. Future Statement Definitions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html)

What else?

Comment: One downside of this approach is if your program has dependencies on  packages incompatible with one the __future __ utility, your program will fail and you don't have much control. For example you use one of simple pypi package and it has "print something".

Thanks anyways it's good question.

Comment: @Shekhar: the effect of `__future__` is localized to a module that imports it. There is no problem with a print statement; only modules that have `from __future__ import print_function` at the top can use the `print()` function.

Answer (score 19):

Many modules these days get rewritten in a way that allows execution on both Python 2 and Python 3. This turns out to be not very hard at all, and in the future it will be very easy to just drop Python 2 support.

Take a look at the [six](http://packages.python.org/six/) module that helps with this task, encapsulating many of the differences in a convenient way:

> Six provides simple utilities for
>   wrapping over differences between
>   Python 2 and Python 3.

Its website (and of course, code) lists a lot of ways to make this possible.

Answer (score 10):

Put the following code into a `py3k.py` module and import it like this: 
`from py3k import *`. You need to put it in every file though, but you can even leave it there if nobody uses Python 2.x anymore or you could just search & replace the import line with whitespace and then remove the file.

```
try:
    from future_builtins import *
except ImportError:
    pass

try:
    input = raw_input
    range = xrange
except NameError:
    pass
```

And this is how my template file looks:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""

"""

from __future__ import division, absolute_import, \
                       print_function, unicode_literals
from utils.py3k import *  # @UnusedWildImport


#
```

Comment: No need to do nested_scopes, generators, with_statement; they all are available when the py3 futures work. Also the zip, map, filter should be imported from `future_builtins` instead...

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about `future_builtins`. What do you mean by 'py3 futures work'?

Comment: That the `generators`, `with_statement` and `nested_scopes` are already in 2.6 so they are unnecessary because `print_function` and `unicode_literals` would complain when trying to import in 2.5...

Comment: Ah, also noted just now: the `from __future__ import` needs to be in every file, it does not affect other files from `py3k.py`

Answer (score 8):

You also need to use the new exception syntaxes, ie no more

```
try:
     raise Exception, "Message"
except Exception, e:
     pass
```

instead you should do:

```
try:
     raise Exception("Message")
except Exception as e:
     pass
```

Also make sure you prefix all your binary strings with a b, ie:

b'This is a binary string'

For a more complete cover of this topic, see http://python3porting.com/noconv.html

Comment: One of the main annoyances is the absence of the `u'string'` syntax in 3. For my money, a terrible decision.

Comment: @Marcin: It's back in 3.3.

Answer (score 8):

Many Python IDE's can be of big help here.

[PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), for example, can be configured to check for compatibility with any range of versions,

[image]

and report issues at any level of severity:

[image]

Comment: Ninja IDE (http://ninja-ide.org/) also has a similar module to help you convert your code to 3.X.

Answer (score 6):

```
try:
    input = raw_input
    range = xrange
except NameError:
    pass
```

Are two ones that spring to mind...

Answer (score 4):

I propose you to give a try for [future library](http://python-future.org/index.html). From their site:

> python-future is the missing compatibility layer between Python 2 and Python 3. It allows you to use a single, clean Python 3.x-compatible codebase to support both Python 2 and Python 3 with minimal overhead.
>
> It provides future and past packages with backports and forward ports of features from Python 3 and 2. It also comes with futurize and pasteurize, customized 2to3-based scripts that helps you to convert either Py2 or Py3 code easily to support both Python 2 and 3 in a single clean Py3-style codebase, module by module.
>
> Notable projects that use python-future for Python 2/3 compatibility are Mezzanine and ObsPy.

Answer (score 1):

Avoing `range()` and `zip()`, using `xrange()` and `itertools.izip()` instead.

Comment: The problem with using `xrange` is that it's missing in Python 3, so the same code has no chance to run there. If one is willing to give up the possible performance benefits of `xrange`, it's better to use `range` instead, making code more python 2 *and* 3 compatible

Comment: @Eli 
Why not do (like my example) a try except to make range = xrange?

Comment: @Eli: But by using xrange etc you can then trivially run 2to3 on the code, while otherwise you might do things like `zip(foo)[2]`, which won't work since the result in Python 3 is not a list.

Comment: @Lennart: agreed about 2to3. It all really depends on the approach one takes to implement the transition.