# How to write Python 2.x as much compatible with Python 3.x as possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compatibility, python-2.x

There are many ways to **include Python 3.x features in Python 2.x**, so code of Python 2.x scripts could be easily converted into Python 3.x in the future. One of these examples is replacing `print` statement with `print()` function:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
```

Is there any list or resource that could give one some ideas how to make Python 2.x code as close to Python 3.x as possible?

Could you give examples of other useful **imports or definitions** that can **make Python 2.x look and behave more like Python 3.x**?

Lets assume we have the latest Python 2.x (2.7.2 at the moment, I believe) at our disposal.

Comment: answers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937251/writing-python-2-7-code-that-is-as-close-to-python-3-x-syntax-as-possible) question may help.

Comment: @BoraCaglayan:  Yes, title is almost exactly the same as this question's :) But unfortunately that link is about Django apps (meaning there is existing code base and you must not spoil the app). My question is about newly created apps, where you do not need to worry that eg. there is a lot of code that uses `print` statement instead of function. This eliminates a lot of problems, I believe.

Comment: @Tadeck: No, the print-function a very trivial problem. Most problems are the same, and much harder. You don't really avoid any of the compatibility trickyness by using Django.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: What I was trying to say is that this question is about creating new app in Python 2.x in a way as close to Python 3.x as possible. I thought using Django creates some problems, as you already have a code that is not compatible with Python 3.x way of coding, thus your options are limited. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Restricting yourself to 2.7 (or even including 2.6) is good. – Restricting yourself to 3.3 or up, would be, too! 3.3 reintroduces `u''` syntax!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm putting the finishing touches on an approximately 5000 line, deduplicating backup program (http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/backshift/) that runs on CPython 2.[567], CPython 3.[0123] (3.3 is still alpha 0), Pypy 1.7 and Jython trunk.  I also tried IronPython, but it was a pretty different thing - it had no standard library, so no backshift love.  Oh, and it can use Cython for its innermost loop, or psyco - but pypy is faster than either, especially on 32 bit systems.

Anyway, I found that to write code that runs equally well on 2.x and 3.x all I needed to do was:

1) print(variable) works the same on both 2.x and 3.x.  print(variable1, variable2) does not.  To 2.x, print(variable) says "evaluate this parenthesized expression, and print the single result using the print statement".  To 3.x, print(variable) says "call the print function on this single result.  So print('abc %d %d' % (1, 2)) works fine in both, because it's a single-valued result, and both grok the % operator for string formatting.

2) Avoid octal constants.  Instead of writing 0755, write (7*64 + 5*8 + 5).

3) To do binary I/O in either, I used my bufsock module.  http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/bufsock.html  I'd os.open a file, and wrap it with bufsock (or use the rawio class in the module).  On 2.x, this would return a string of bytes encoded as 8 bit character strings.  On 3.x, this would return a bytes object, which acts much like a list of small integers.  Then I'd just pass around one or the other, testing with "isinstance(foo, str)" as needed to distinguish between the two.  I did this, because to a backup program, bytes are bytes - I didn't want to mess around with encodings fouling up saving data reliably, and not all encodings round trip well.

4) When doing exceptions, avoid the "as" keyword.  Instead, use EG:

```
  try:
     self.update_timestamp()
  except (OSError, IOError):
     dummy, utime_extra, dummy = sys.exc_info()
     if utime_extra.errno == errno.ENOENT:
```

5) A bunch of modules were renamed in the transition from 2.x to 3.x.  So try importing either one into an otherwise-empty module, with something like:

```
try:
   from anydbm import *
except ImportError:
   from dbm import *
```

...this would appear in a module by itself, with a name EG adbm.py.  Then anytime I needed a key-value store, I'd import adbm instead of the two different things needed for 2.x or 3.x directly.  Then I'd pylint everything but that stubby module, adbm.py - and things like it that pylint disliked.  The idea was to pylint everything possible, with exceptions to the "everything's gotta pylint" rule in a tiny module all by itself, one exception per module.

6) It helps a lot to set up automatic unit tests and system tests that run on 2.x and 3.x, and then test frequently on at least one 2.x interpreter as well as at least one 3.x interpreter.  I also run pylint against my code often, albeit only a pylint that checked for 2.5.x compliance - I started the project before pylint got 3.x support.

7) I set up a small "python2x3" module that has a few constants and callables to make life easier: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/python2x3/trunk/python2x3.py

8) b'' literals don't work in 2.5, though they sort of work in 2.[67].  Instead of trying to preprocess or something, I set up a constants_mod.py that had lots of things that would normally be b'' literals in 3.x, and converted them from a simple string to whatever the "bytes" type is for 2.x or 3.x.  So they're converted once on module import, not over and over at runtime.  If you're targeting 2.[67] and up, there's perhaps a better way, but when I started the Pypy project was only compatible with 2.5, and Jython still is.

9) In 2.x, long integers have an L suffix.  In 3.x, all integers are long.  So I just went with avoiding long integer constants as much as possible; 2.x will promote an integer to long as necessary, so this seems to work out fine for most things.

10) It helps a LOT to have a bunch of python interpreters around to test with.  I built 2.[567] and 3.[0123] and stashed them in /usr/local/cpython-x.y/ for easy testing.  I also put some Pypy's and Jython's in /usr/local, again for easy testing.  Having a script to automate the CPython builds was rather valuable.

I believe these were all the contortions I required to get a highly portable python codebase in a nontrivial project.  The one big omission to the list I've written above, is that I'm not trying to use unicode objects - that's something someone else is probably better qualified to comment on.

HTH

Comment: hey, you're aware that sys.exc_info() trick will make pypy cry?

Comment: No, I wasn't.  Thanks for mentioning that.  What's needed to fix it in Pypy?

Comment: Does it really?  This seems to work:

>>>> try:
....    dummy = 1/0
.... except:
....    dummy, foo, dummy = sys.exc_info()
....    print foo
....
integer division by zero
>>>>

Comment: it works, but sys.exc_info() makes the whole stack of frames appear. This is fine for debuggers or such (as it was designed), but for just having an exception object it's a huge overkill. JIT will abort tracing and compiling and also quit assembler.

Comment: For the ones concerned with `sys.exc_info()`: there is no need to actually avoid using `except ... as ...`, if you support only Python 2.6+ and no older versions.

Answer (score 8):

You should check out [Porting Python Code to 3.0](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PortingPythonToPy3k).  While it's aimed at porting, it answers essentially the same question; you just won't be going all the way.

Comment: Thanks. I am especially interested in 2nd option from the link you have given: "_make code run unmodified in both Python 2 and Python 3_". This option is the closest to what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 8):

There is [a whole chapter](http://python3porting.com/noconv.html) on this in "[Porting to Python 3](http://python3porting.com/)". Also don't miss the appendixes, that list language differences with workarounds to support both languages.

You probably want to use the [six library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six), although it's possible to do it without it.

Answer (score 5):

[Porting Python 2 code to Python 3](http://docs.python.org/howto/pyporting.html) is part of the official documentation and, still not directly answering your question, could help.

Answer (score 2):

I have this at the top of my Python 2.7 script template:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
from future_builtins import ascii, filter, hex, map, oct, zip
```

Comment: That's nowhere near enough for practical use. And future_builtins doesn't exist in Python 3, so this code will in fact not run on Python 3.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more practical to keep the furure_builtins module in Python 3 standard library, in order to make it easier to support both Python2 and Python3 version from a common codebase?

Answer (score 1):

Since it hasn't been mentioned yet: I found this [cheat sheet](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html) to be really useful for this exact purpose.